# Question regarding Wightman's "transformation law" axiom for QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, foundations

On the [Wightman axioms Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms), the W2 axiom describes the effect of Poincare transformations on the quantum field. It states:
$$U(a,L)^\dagger A(x) U(a,L)=S(L)A(L^{-1}(x-a))$$
where A is the quantum field, $a$ is a spacetime translation, $L$ is an element of the Lorentz group, $U$ is a unitary representation of the Poincare group and $S$ is a representation of the Lorentz group (or its double cover).

Taking $L$ to be the identity in this equation we get $U(a,\text{id})^\dagger A(x) U(a,\text{id})=A(x-a)$, so given the value of the field at a single spacetime point $x$, we can work out the value at any other spacetime point $y$ by applying the relevant unitary. This seems wrong, since in order to calculate how a field evolves, we need initial conditions, not just its value at a single point.

What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2):

Take the translation $a$ to be a time translation $a=t$, so $U(t)=e^{-i\hat Ht}$ where $\hat H$ is the Hamiltonian. Now $\hat H$ involves  an integral over all space, so  it is making use of the  state of the entire $t=0$ time slice. That's where  your initial conditions are found.

Comment: This feels like the right explanation, but I don't see how the equation could mean this, unless notation is somehow being abused.

Comment: The operator $A(x,t)$ is *very complicated* funtion of $A(x,0)$ and knows everything that could possibly happen. To find a measured value of $A(x,t)$ you need to apply it to a state at time $t=0$ and that selects a subset of the possibilites.

Comment: @JacobDrori To work out the effect at an arbitrary point, you need to use the (unitary) spatial translations in addition to the (unitary) time translation. You can think of the spatial translations as populating a Cauchy surface with the initial data, starting with the field-operator-at-one-point, and then the time-translation propagates all that data forward/backward in time.

Comment: @mike stone by A(x,0) do you mean "the operator-valued function A(_,0)" or just "the operator A(x,0), for some fixed x"? If the latter, then I still do not understand, since it seems the value of the field at one point can be calculated from a single value at some other point.

Comment: @chiral anomaly Are you saying that you can compute the field over all of spacetime if you know its value at just one point?

Comment: @chiral anomaly Yes, I meant value in the sense of "operator-valued". I'm pretty astounded that the operator at one point contains all the information about the entire field. Clearly I'm missing some important understanding.

Comment: @JacobDrori The operator $A(x)$ at one point (say $x=0$) doesn't contain all of that info, but the combination of $A(0)$ with the whole group of translation operators $U(a)$ does. Actually, we only need the generators of the translation operators, so one operator per spacetime dimension, together with $A(0)$, is sufficient to generate $A(x)$ for all $x$. If you're comfortable with the idea in non-relativistic QM that the Hamiltonian $H$ generates the position observables $X(t)$ for all $t$, given just $X(0)$ and $H$, this is the same idea, but with translations in space as well as in time.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get it.  But I'm still confused about the actual meaning of Lorentz invariance in this framework. Is the idea that $S(L)$ commutes with the translation operators $U(a)$? This seems like a natural requirement so that Lorentz boosts don't affect the dynamics, i.e. so that all observers can use the same evolution operators regardless of their velocities. However I've not seen this explicitly stated anywhere - is it true? Or something along these lines?